# Running 2 functions in parallel and wait for one of them to return

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency

How can I run 2 functions in parallel and wait for the return of one of them.

Basically what I have is a keypad, which I call a function where you enter a pin and a function where i read an NFC Tag. So which one returns first I will use the return value on the rest of the code.

I've looked into threading and what I get from it, is that it hangs until all the threads are finished.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You could let the threads call a method when they are done that only handles one call. Hopefully the following shows what I mean:

```
# consider this as pseudo code, I am commuting right know

def task1(callback):
    # do something
    callback(*args)

class SomeCallback:
    available = True
    def __call__(*args):
        if not SomeCallback.available: return  # a second call will do nothing
        # work with nfc tag response or keyphrase
        SomeCallback.available = False
        # maybe even end all other threads here
        

thread = Thread(target=task1, (callback,))
thread.start()
# start a second thread or do the other thing on the mainthread
```